# how to get all the headerfiles which are used in compiling?

Tags: c, dependencies, clang, header-files, compiler-optimization

I am compiling my SW using Clang (android30) and as my SW is really big, I want to extract only the files which are necessary to compile, so that I can have a smaller SW.

is there anyway to have a list of all the dependencies (header-files and .c file)?

I am using make framework to compie which looks like this:

P

```
PRJ_ANDROID_COMPILE          := $(XXX)/aarch64-linux-android30-clang
PRJ_ANDROID_COMPILE_COMMAND   = $(X) \
                                $(addprefix -D,$(XX)) \
                                $(addprefix -I ,$(XXXX) $(XXXXX)) \
                                $(addprefix -isystem ,$(PRJ_ANDROID_SYSTEM_INCLUDES)) \
                                $(addprefix -include ,$(PRJ_ANDROID_HEADER_INCLUDES)) \
                                -c $(abspath $<) \
                                -o $(XXXXX)/$(notdir$*)$(FRW_PROCESSOR_OBJ_EXT);
```

Comment: It really doesn't matter if your header files are large, or if you include a lot of them. If the function declarations, structures definitions, or macros in them aren't used they will not contribute to the size of the executable program. Try optimize for size (`-Os`, if `-O3` isn't good enough). Use different link-time optimizations to (if possible) remove duplicate code.

Comment: There's gcc / `clang -M` to print dependencies instead of compiling or preprocessing.  If you use it without other options, it includes all dependencies, including system headers, for each `.c` file, in Makefile format.  It should be straightforward to take the union of that set, i.e. eliminate duplicates.  Normally you wouldn't want to include system headers in a source distribution, but you could filter by path, or use some options like `-MF` instead of plain `-M` if you want to find what subset of a large source tree is needed to build some part of it.

Comment: Also remember that any decent header file will use [header include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) or [`#pragma once`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) to prevent multiple inclusion in the same [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). So even if you include the same header file multiple times in a single translation unit, it should only be included once anyway. And if you need a header file in different translation units, you must simply include it in all the translation units where it's needed.

Comment: What SW do you want to make smaller? The source files that are needed to build? The binary that is executed?

Comment: To get your program smaller you might check if your linker supports selective linking. Some old linkers always included all code from a C file whenever one function was referenced. In those cases splitting files to only have one function per file would help. Modern linkers typically don't need that as they only include functions that are actually used.

Comment: I don't want to compress it. currently I have a big package with all my components and the complete source code. I want to create a smaller working copy with only what is necessary for my build under my source tree.

Comment: Thanks Peter, but I am using a make framework to compile. should I only add -MF to it and will it automatically generate the results? I update in my post how I am building, please help me how to do this